# Copying multiple lines from python console to main script brings in the line break '...'

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm running Pycharm 2020 on Win10. Today it started to give me this problem. How do I prevent the '...' line break from being copied?

[image: screenshot 1]

**UPDATE:** for those that don't believe this feature ever existed, I tested on a different computer with Pycharm 2019 and here is what it did:

[image: screenshot 2]

**UPDATE:** PyCharm has gone back to normal by itself.

Comment: do you mean you type the program into python console?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP says problem "has fixed itself."

Comment: @TomServo I didn't find a close button so I updated it. How would I do that?

Comment: Well, you actually can, please upvote JetBrains issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39725

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.
This is not an issue of PyCharm, if you copy&paste from the console/terminal, you will copy the dots `...` as well.

---

Edit:

you can use the history button as shown below to get a clean list of the commands you typed in the console.

[image: history button]

Comment: But if you look at the question, he said "it started to give me ..." which mean it wasn't like that before, I tested with it too, and it seems like Pycharm has no such feature that removes `...`, I am confused.

Comment: I'm not aware of a such feature. If you write your code in the console, then copy the code from there, you'll copy all the text the console is showing, included the dots `...`

Comment: Now I'm confused... It used to get rid of the dots automatically for me... Maybe my luck ran out ;)

Comment: you can use the history button as shown in my reply. I edited the message right now

Comment: @YusefMaali Thank you. That could be an alternative. I no longer have this problem anymore as PyCharm fixed itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to uncheck the option below and it works:

[image]